# Is it possible to group dependencies in maven?

Tags: java, maven

My goal is to create a distribution package (zip) with the following layout:

```
- application.jar
- libWebService
    - web-service.jar
- libUtil
    - guava.jar
...
```

The `application.jar`references the libraries in the separate lib folders in its `MANIFEST.MF`. The point with this layout is, that the dependencies are grouped semantically but are all normal maven dependencies defined in the `pom.xml` of the module that produces the `application.jar`.

Is there a simple way to create such kind of distrubtion with maven?

I know that I can use the `maven-dependency-plugin` (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its goal `copy-dependencies` to copy all dependencies of the current module (incl. its transitive dependencies) into a given output folder. With the exclude/include options I could even filter the dependencies and by invoking the plugin multiple times I could create the desired folder structure, although such kind of solutions would not be easy to maintain. But this solution still lacks the feature that the `MANIFEST.MF` file has to refer to the different folders. The `maven-jar-plugin` allows me to define one `classpathPrefix` for the complete jar but not a separate one for each dependency.

Comment: You might want to look at maven-assembly-plugin, but normally Maven isn't really fit for this.

Comment: I'd go for grouping the dependencies into separate projects that your main project will depend on in the end. That way, you'll depend on just three projects, and each of them can be built differently. As @xea already said, maven-assembly-plugin is likely a good choice for incorporating all three into your main project.